# adding class to div that applys a gradient on click only works first time

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

I have a form that has a few radio buttons and a text input. Using JavaScript I apply a background gradient to the text fields wrapper on click and remove it on click of the radio buttons. When I click on the text input a class is applied that has the gradient via css and when I click the radio button it is removed, but when I re-click on the text input the gradient is not applied again.. and ideas why?
Side note, the border is applied and removed every time...just not the gradient.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" >
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" >
<div id="textInputWrapper">
    <input type="text" id="textInput">
</div>
<script>
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
    $('#textInputWrapper').css('background', ' #17a2dc');
    $('#textInputWrapper label').css('color', 'white');
    $('#textInputWrapper').removeClass('gradient');
});
$('#textInput').click(function () {
    $('#textInputWrapper label').css('color', '#606060');
    $('#textInputWrapper').addClass('gradient');
});
</script>
<style>
.gradient {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,     rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(52%,rgba(188,188,188,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(126,126,126,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#7e7e7e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border:7px white solid;
}
#textInputWrapper {
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
$('#textInputWrapper').css('background', ' #17a2dc');
```

Once you click on the radio button, this line adds inline CSS which will override the styles associated with the `.gradient` class. Instead try modifying the `#textInputWrapper` CSS like this:

```
#textInputWrapper:not(.gradient) {
  width:100%;
  background: #17a2dc;
}

/* Move the gradient style declaration after the #textInputWrapper declaration */
.gradient {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,     rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(52%,rgba(188,188,188,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(126,126,126,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(188,188,188,1) 52%,rgba(126,126,126,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#7e7e7e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  border:7px white solid;
}
```

Basically, keep your CSS segregated so that adding and removing the `.gradient` class is the only thing triggering the UI change.

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/godfrzero/eLBDU/)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because, inline styles are loaded with more priority than defined ones.

Add new style in CSS block:

```
.blue {
    background: #17a2dc
}
```

And change your JavaScript:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
  $('#textInputWrapper').removeClass('gradient');
  $('#textInputWrapper').addClass('blue');
  $('#textInputWrapper label').css('color', 'white');
});

$('#textInput').click(function () {
  $('#textInputWrapper').removeClass('blue');
  $('#textInputWrapper').addClass('gradient');
  $('#textInputWrapper label').css('color', '#606060');
});
```

An example http://jsfiddle.net/Kj7uL/